# Blockchain.info : "Insufficient Funds Available"

Tags: api, blockchain.info

When I sent bitcoin to an address by using Blockchain.info API, I got "Insufficient Funds Available" error. Like below..

[API Request]

https://blockchain.info/fr/merchant/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/payment?password=password1&second_password=password2&to=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&amount=1000

[API Response]

{"error":"Insufficient Funds Available: 0 Needed: 11000"}

I don't know why because my account has sufficient balance.

The error is not always happened. I guess that I get an error when my wallet has unconfirmed transactions. But not sure..

If you know the reason, I really, really need to know it. Thanks.

[Update]

I am finding the reason. I have only one bitcoin address in my Blockchain.info account.

The followings are the state of the confirmation about my bitcoin address and the API call result.

```
Case1 "Insufficient Funds Available" error occurred

balance = 1586000;
hash = 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
Received = 12166000;
sent = 10580000;
"unconfirmed_balance" = "-11000";
"unconfirmed_received" = 1575000;
"unconfirmed_sent" = 1586000;

Case2 OK

balance = 1575000;
hash = 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
received = 13741000;
sent = 12166000;
"unconfirmed_balance" = 0;
"unconfirmed_received" = 0;
"unconfirmed_sent" = 0;
```

Comment: It says you have 11000 unconfirmed in balance. Can you post the txid (which is safe to do) to show the BTC being deposited to the address in question? Otherwise provide more details on when you deposited the funds and any other details. Can you login normally and see your balance? And are you certain your url should have password fields in it?

Comment: Please post the answer as an "answer post" instead of answering your question in the question.